# How does for loop inside a recursive function not create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

```js
let elm = document.getElementById("list")

function countChars(elm) { 
    if(elm.nodeType === 3) { 
        return elm.nodeValue.length
    }
    
    let count = 0;
    console.log(count)
    for(var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) { 
        count += countChars(child)
        console.log(i)
    }

    return count;
}

console.log("count is: " + countChars(elm));
```

```html
<ol id="list">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

I can't understand how does this not create an infinite loop.

When `child` gets assigned to an element node, and the `countChars(child)` re-triggers the function:
1 - does the below `console.log()` get executed? if so, when?
2 - when the first `if(elm.nodeType === 3)` does not match, does the `for loop` get triggered again? If so, shouldn't that create an infinite loop? If it doesn't get re-triggered again, why? what happens?

The `console.log()` beneath the `let count = 0` shows `0` the second iteration, so therefore the loop does get triggered again? If so, how is that not an infinite loop? I can't explain to myself what happens.

Hopefully some of you can explain it.

**Just to clarify:**
My question is, if the `for loop` is re-triggered every time, then that means the `i` is instantiated every time to `0`, so therefore, that create an infinite loop. Obviously I understand that when a `childNode` is undefined, the conditional statement inside the loop is `false` so the loop stops, but that is not my question.

Comment: Some nodes will have no child nodes, so from that depth the function just returns. Note also that each invocation, including the recursive ones, get their own private local variables.

Comment: yeah, this is what I don't get. The second iteration `childNode[1]` is element node, so the first `if` condition is not met.. so what happens next? Does the `for loop` get re-triggered again? If yes, then how is that not an infinite loop?

Comment: what do you mean by `get their own private local variables`?

Comment: It's a different `for` loop at each level of the recursion. Each loop covers the children of **one** node. For each of those children, the function is recursively called, and inside that new layer of recursion `childNode[i]` is represented by `elm`. That `for` loop will do nothing at all when `elm.childNodes` is an empty list, so that fork of the recursion will finish. That will happen to *all* forks of the recursion, because the DOM is finite.

Comment: Calling the function recursively makes a completely new invocation context. It's not the same `i`, not the same `elm`, etc. The term "re-triggered" is really not accurate. There will be a `for` loop in the recursively-called function, but it will operate on a different node in the DOM.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: change the count function so that it takes an additional argument, a "recursion level" counter. When a recursive call is made, pass the current level plus 1. Then your `console.log()` statements can show both `i` and `level`, to illustrate that it won't keep going "down" forever, because the DOM comes to an end at the leaves of the tree.

Comment: May be read this to understand about recursion first? https://javascript.info/recursion

Comment: @aksappy There is just one little tiny thing missing with that long explanation.. WHAT IS THE RETURNED VALUE OF `pow(x, n-1)`??? This is a 5 page essay explanation without covering the very basic of the basic and most fundamental key aspect of this whole concept. I cannot comprehend what is the returned value of `pow(x, n-1)`? The function is triggered with these arguments, but where is the return value specified?? This just triggers the same function.. so where is the return value?? Why can't somebody explain to me this most basic and key aspect of this concept...

Comment: @happy_story the return value is in the `pow()` function at the `return` statement (there might be more than one). It's just like with any other function. Note that `return` returns from **one** invocation of a function; a `return` in a stack of recursive calls just applies to the topmost recursive call.

Comment: @happy_story a computer do not use the code that you wrote as is. It creates a representation (machine language) and in that, the variable names may not count or elm etc.. There are memory locations/references instead. So whenever a function starts, the instructions tell the computer to allocate memory for count and elm and so on. This differentiates the execution context. The return value is also a memory location, which is read/returned to the caller (read callstacks)

Comment: @aksappy This doesn't remotely answer my question, but thanks for trying anyway. I already understood how it works in general, but I still can't get my head around about the particular case I described in this question. Since every new function is triggered with the same value, there is no change in the value. So, where's the decrementation or change coming from.

Comment: Every function does not get triggered with the same value. Every function is triggered with the childNode of the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was suggesting in a comment. You can see that the "level" goes up and then back down.

```js
let elm = document.getElementById("list")

function countChars(elm, level) {
    level = level || 0;
    if(elm.nodeType === 3) { 
        return elm.nodeValue.length
    }
    
    let count = 0;
    for(var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) { 
        count += countChars(child, level + 1)
        console.log("level: " + level + " i: " + i + " count so far: " + count);
    }

    return count;
}

console.log("total count is: " + countChars(elm));
```

```html
<ol id="list">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I really have hard time understanding this. I am not getting what happens when `childNode[1]` is elemetn node, and the `countChars(child)` re-triggers the same function with element node, and therefore the first `if` is not matched. What happens then? If a new for loop is created, what happened to the previous one? If a new `for loop` is created, how is `i` still incremented then? Shouldn't it be instantiated again from 0?

Comment: Think of it as a pile of function calls. The initial function call is at the bottom. Each *recursive* call adds a new function call onto the pile. The new function does not know that it's part of a recursive sequence. When the function at the top of the pile is finished, it returns its count and disappears from the pile, while the function below it resumes its own `for` loop.

Comment: I don't understand if a new `for` loop is triggered again, then why is `i` not 0 again? If `i` is 0 every time a new `for` loop is triggered, then there should be an infinite loop of just 000000 etc. Why is `i` not 0? Why? I don't understand this. And also, why does the function `return` the `count`, even before `for` loop has finished? The last `return` should be executed only AFTER `for` loop has finished, but it never does!! The `for` loop always ENDS at the second iteration, and then a new one is triggered and again ends at 2nd iteration! What am I missing!?

Comment: Every **call** to a function creates a new scope for all the function's local variables. The `i` in one call is not the same `i` as in another call. Consider two unrelated functions that both have a local variable `i`. If one of those functions calls the other, you don't expect the value of `i` in the target function to mess with the `i` in the calling function, right? There's no difference in recursive function calls.

Comment: If you were doing this by hand, you might have a piece of paper on which you would keep track of the variables, updating them (on paper) step by step. When a recursive call is made, you get a *fresh* piece of paper and place it on top, and continue. When that recursive call is finished, you take off that top piece of paper and throw it away. Underneath will be the previous piece of paper with all the variable values just as they were when you covered it up.

Comment: So, I understood how the recursive functions work in general, but I still struggle with this particular case, because, every time `childNode[1]` is triggered, and `count += countChars(child)` is executed, and `countChars(child)` is triggered with the element Node as argument, I don't see where is the decrementation or change coming from? In all the examples I saw, the recursive function is always triggered differently, either `(x-1)` or something like that, so there is a decrementation or change in the arguments, but in this one with the node, where is the change? It's the same node, no?

Comment: where is the change coming from?

Comment: The first call to `countChars()` starts at some point in the DOM.  The "decrementation" happens when the recursive call is made: instead of starting at the original starting DOM node, the recursive call starts *one step down* the DOM tree. It starts from a *child* of the starting node. The subsequent recursive calls do the same thing. Ultimately, the process will reach a node that has no children.

Comment: I think I finally get it. The only thing I don't get now is why is the final result 31, and not 35? The `length` of textNode is 5 `#text`, and the length of all the innerHTML `test1/2/3` is again 5, so the way I calculated it, it should be 35. Why is it 31?

Comment: @happy_story It's confusing because of the way browsers build text nodes, and they do that for white space too even if the white space does not matter to the HTML rendering engine. Also, different browsers may build text nodes for white space and line breaks in different ways.

Comment: Also note that this code is summing the sizes only of the *text* nodes. The HTML markup is not counted.

Comment: You mean `#` this is not counted? But it is. The length of all textNodes shows as 5, and the textNodes which in all cases are just empty spaces, is just `#text` this.

Comment: So, it seems that the last childNode[6] is again `#text` but its length is 1, and not 5, like it is for all the others. This is why the end result is 31. Weird.

Comment: There are more text nodes than just the visible ones in the `<li>` blocks. All the whitespace gets text nodes as well.

Comment: Also I don't know what you mean by "#text".

Comment: When you console.log the text nodes, it gives you `#text`, which is where the length comes from.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me out. I really appreciate you.

Comment: No, that is not where the length comes from. What you want to look at is `elm.nodeValue`, because that''s what the code pays attention to. If you do that, you'll see that many of the text nodes contain nothing but white space, but they count too.

Comment: yes, but the textNodes that are only empty space have a length of 5, which means means `#text` this gives them the length.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give an explanation as to what is going on here.

First, the OP has a simple recursive function. The function `countChars` takes an initial element (ol in this case) and loops through its childNodes and recursively tries to find the total number of characters within all the elements.

```js
let elm = document.getElementById("list"); // scope of elm is global

function countChars(elm) { // scope of elm is limited to this function
    if(elm.nodeType === 3) { 
        return elm.nodeValue.length
    }
    
    let count = 0;
    console.log(count)
    for(var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) { 
        count += countChars(child) // This is a childNode of the elm
        console.log(i)
    }

    return count; //This return goes back to the count inside for loop
}
```

Here is a pseudocode of how the loop works, let me know if you need more information than this.

1. pass ol to countChars (last line in the code)
2. take first child of ol (textNode), countChar
3. #text is found
4. return number of chars
5. add to count, no more childNodes for #text
6. take second child of ol (liNode), countChar
7. take first child of liNode, countChar
8. #text is found, return number of chars
9. add to count, no more childNodes for #text
10. Loop continues (GOTO 2)

The given code will not generate an infinite loop, because no two invocations of `countChars` are the same. Every call to `countChar` creates a new frame and pushes into call stack. The previous call/frame waits for this new call/frame to complete. The returned value (count) gets added into the previous frame's count (scoped) and when all the frames are executed, the program returns the final value, the first frame's count.

So, if you have three li elements, each with a text of 5 chars, why is the count 31 and not 15?

This is because an ordered list is rendered consider order and spacing. They have #text nodes (which is not in the code, but in the render), so they also get added into count in the `countChars`. So, we have 7 #text nodes, 6 of them have 5 characters, the 7th and last one has 1 character.

Here is a screenshot of the console logs to show what is going on. I have added a pipe `|` before and after every char.
[image: Console logs from Developer Tools]

Note - Please take the explanation to recursion with a grain of salt. I tried to generalize and I am not an expert on the internals of a browser/js.